# What fantasy book has twins (except one's blue) and a cloaked ice bear on the cover?

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I remember only the cover of this book. A fantasy novel released before 2007. The cover of the book had a twin pair where one of the twins were blue, and if I am not mistaken, there was an ice bear wearing a kind of cloak in the background... sorry I do not have much more to offer

Comment: “a twin pair” — of what? Babies?

Comment: Blue skin? Hair? Clothing?

Comment: Whoa, this is the shortest question I have seen that got answer so quickly. Talk about memorable book cover design.

Comment: I've never heard of the term "ice bear" and I'm a 40 yr old native English speaker, yet my mind automatically filled in the gap with a polar bear. Not sure how or why, but I didn't even think twice about it. Also, the way the title is worded, I was somehow thinking the polar bear was blue and one of the twins, with the other one being human. I never know what my mind is going to come up with sometimes...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [*Phenomena*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Phenomena) novels by Ruben Eliassen.

[image: Cover of the first book, *Profetiens Utvalgte*, showing Ilke, with blue skin, and All, with cloaked bear (Arol) in the background, as well as Sha-ra, their wizard father and mentor]

> *Phenomena* is a series of Norwegian Young Adult fantasy books written by Ruben Eliassen. The series follows the elf boy Alk and his twin sister Ilke, which according to an old prophecy has the power to defeat Tarkan, the fürst of darkness, and by that free their world from his evil regime.
>
> The series takes place in Aldra, a country in the world Erda, controlled by the Sherpa, the Dark Lord and his evil forces. The elves are slaves by Tarkan's servants the mortoks but two elves, Harti and Khiri, manages to bring their newborn children out of captivity and to the wise vizard Sha-ra's Castle. Here will the children, the twins Alk and Ilke, raised in freedom. It turns out that Sha-ra knows an ancient prophecy, recorded in the Phenomena; the book of visdom. The prophecy says that two elf children will rise up and fight Tarkan on the Gredom fields. These two children are Alk and Ilke, and they go out to fulfil prophecy and defeat evil.
>
> Throughout the series, we follow Alk and Ilke and their adventures leading up to the unavoidable battle that will decide the fate of the world. In addition to the twins, we also get to know their adoptive father Sha-ra, their big brother figure Arol, Jolsah the mortok prince, Azur an escaped slave, and Millian who have been transported to Aldra from our own world and many others.

Possible confounding factor, it doesn't look like there's an official English translation.

Found with a search for *fantasy novel twins ice  "blue skin"*

Comment: This makes more sense than my answer. :) +1 Mine was the first thing I thought of...

Comment: At least there's a bear in the picture. Is it an ice bear? I don't know what an "ice bear" is, do you? I thought it might mean an ice sculpture of a bear.

Comment: @user14111, I would assume a polar bear.

Comment: @user14111 It's very much possible the person who asked the question isn't English, and there are a lot of languages where the word for polar bear literally translates to "ice bear". For example, dutch (ijsbeer) and german (Eisbär) both have this.

Comment: @user14111 Not sure if it's an "ice bear" but it definitively doesn't looks like a nice one.

Comment: @DennisvanGils "Ice bear" is also another name for a polar bear in English; it's in the OED. Much less common than "polar bear", at least in my neck of the woods; I never heard it before. So I learned something new. Just because I've been wallowing in ignorance for 80 years, that doesn't mean I have to go on being ignorant my whole life.

Comment: @user14111 - You look good for 80! ;)

Comment: The OP's name certainly *looks* Norwegian.

Comment: MY GUY YOU FOUND IT! man I love the internet <3

Comment: I only assumed there was an english version, but if there isn't then that makes the finding just even more impressive. How did you gather that it was this book from my vauge description?

Comment: :) I provided the search terms. You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I think that one thing that helped was assuming "were blue" meant "had blue skin" and to use quote marks to ensure those words were in sequence.

Answer (score 11):

This may not be what you're thinking of, but as we don't have any details of the plot, this reminds me of a [Magic Tree House](https://www.magictreehouse.com) book called [*Winter of the Ice Wizard*](https://www.magictreehouse.com/books/125131/winter-of-the-ice-wizard):

> Merlin the magician and Morgan le Fay have disappeared, and in order to find them, Jack and Annie journey with their friends Teddy and Kathleen to the Land-Behind-the-Clouds, a frozen kingdom of ice and snow. There they must overcome their fears and solve the Ice Wizard's riddle, because if Jack and Annie don't complete their mission in time, Merlin and Morgan will disappear forever!
>
> <sup><sub>(From link above...)</sub></sup>

Here's the cover:

[image: book cover]

They're not actually twins. Jack is Annie's older brother and the thing wearing a blue cloak in the background is not exactly a bear, but looks like one; he's a wizard. Also, this book was released in 2004. This seems to match some of your description.